# Div vertical and horizontale

Tags: css, html

is it possble to do that in HTML/CSS : [desired result](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/7631/resvoulu.jpg)

There is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
      <style>       body {        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;      }      
      .box {
      border: 3px solid black;
      background-color:pink;  
      width:auto;
      display: table;   
      white-space: nowrap;}            

  .com {
  background-color:yellow;     
  border: 3px solid black;                               
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-40px) ;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-40px)  ;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-40px)  ;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-40px) ;

  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0% ;
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 0% ;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% ;
  transform-origin: 0% 0% ;
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }

</style> 

  <title>css</title>
  </head>
  <body >

  <div>

  <div style="float:left; border: 1px solid black;   ">
  <div class=box>DIV-111111</div>
  <div class=com>DIV-2222222222</div>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left; border: 1px solid black;   ">
  <div class=box>DIV-33</div>
  <div class=com>DIV-44444444</div>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left; border: 1px solid black;   ">
  <div class=box>DIV-55555555555555555</div>
  <div class=com>DIV-6666666666666666666666</div>
  </div>

  </div>

  </body>
</html>`
```

But, the result is not good.. there is a blank space between the pink div because of the yellow div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
position:absolute;
```

to your com class.

Comment: to get the thin black line to show up, you need to explicitly set the height of that element.